# GetAngle of revolute2 returns always 0

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm using gazebo 2.2.5, because it ships with Ubuntu. However, for my revolute2 joints I can't get the angular position of the 2nd axis: joint->GetAngle(1) returns always 0.
GetVelocity(1) as well as GetAngle(0) and GetVelocity(0) work as expected.

I found in this forum that this bug should have been fixed in Gazebo 1.4 [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/992/getting-angle-of-2-dof-joint/) - but apparently it's not.

I would like to know if this is a bug, and if it is fixed in later versions? I would prefer to stay with the gazebosim that comes with ubuntu, unless there is a really good reason to upgrade and resign the convenience that prepacked versions offer...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7650/getangle-of-revolute2-returns-always-0/) by [Moritz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1049/moritz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo currently does not ship with Ubuntu. You have probably installed ROS, which brings in Gazebo2.

The issue that you have referred to is related to your question, but addresses a different problem.

Access to the angle of the second axis of a revolute2 joint has not been available in ODE. We have an outstanding [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/380/fix-hinge2joint-getangleimpl) to fix this.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moritz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1049/moritz/) on 2014-12-08**:
Thanks. I have a workaround: I just connect multiple 1DOF revolute joints via massless links.